# Winforms RadTextBox control validating event triggered twice

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I am doing a database validation on the TextBox validating event. I am also using the e.Cancel = True if the data is invalid. The problem is that the validating event is triggered twice ultimately causing the SQL also to run twice, and I don't want that to happen (coz sometime the query is resource intensive).

**Steps:**

1. Drag & drop a RadTextBox & a RadLabel to the Form.
2. For the RadTextBox validating event use the below code.
3. Run the application, focus the RadTextBox & then click on the label. Then if you check the output window of visual studio you will    notice that the console has logged that the validating event was    actually triggered twice. (The event runs twice only when I try to    click a RadButton or a RadLabel)

I noticed this bug when I was checking my queries in SQL Server Profiler & the query gets executed twice, which is unnecessary. I also checked with actual wincontrols & this issue doesn't exist in them.

How do I fix this issue ?

Here a sample code to replicate the behavior

```
Private Sub RadTextBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles RadTextBox1.Validating
    Console.WriteLine("VALIDATING EVENT TRIGGERED")        
    e.Cancel = True    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a known issue with RadTextBox: [issue link](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/154/Feedback/Details/133223-fix-radtextbox-the-validating-event-is-fired-twice-when-the-validation-is-canc)

Perhaps you can try [RadTextBoxControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-textboxcontrol-overview.html) for your needs?

Comment: I logged this error to telerik & they accepted that it was actually a bug. RadTextBoxControl has the same problem.